# Automating changeset merges in TFS based on work-item workflow

Tags: automation, .net-framework, team-foundation-server

I'm working to automate our merge process for changesets related to specific work items, but I'm kind of at a loss as to where to start.

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm almost completely new to TFS and DevOps entirely. I'll try and be as clear as possible, but if there is anything I need to elaborate on, please sound off in the comments.

---

Currently, part of the manual process of *completing* a work item is to manually merge the relevant changeset. This is done by requesting the merge from someone with the proper permissions to do so, which may or may not be the dev responsible for the changeset.

I've done a bit of research, and have come up with two ideas:

1. Create a custom TFS plugin to listen for a certain Work Item event (using the `ISubscriber` interface) and perform the merge

   or
2. In the Work Item's workflow, add a custom action to the transition between stages 'x' and 'y'

I'm fairly confident that this can be done with a custom TFS plugin, but it also seems like that would be a lot more work than is necessary. Can TFS Power Tools be used to set something like this up?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for StackOverflow community.

Comment: Well, if your question is 'where to start', I would say you already figured that out (microsoft.teamfoundation API). Or, is your real question on how one of these would be implemented? 
The title suggests you want solution using 'work item workflow' however you also seem adamant about a tfs plugin. So maybe you can clarify.

Comment: I guess my question is a combination of "are either of them valid" and if both of them are, which would be the simpler solution? I'm certain I could do this with the API, but would it be simpler using something like TFS Power Tools? And if so, how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deciding on option 1. I don't think that creating a custom action in the work item's workflow would be capable of doing what I want. [Related Discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f40db2f-3440-4965-884d-dd915fdc03bc/work-item-action-list?forum=tfsworkitemtracking#4ba34905-b4e5-463b-8f0e-25f6804b11a6)

So like I said, I'm choosing to write a TFS Plugin. It sounds like the API is capable of automating merging of changesets. Now I just need to get my local TFS server to [recognize my plugin!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098326/debugging-tfs-plugin-locally)